# Calling UDF function and get Task not serializable Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

The code was working fine until I made some changes because
I need to implement `rotatekey` as an `UDF function` but
I missed something because I am getting this error

```sh
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  ...
  ...
at playground.RotatingKeys.run(RotatingKeys.scala:25)
at playground.Main$.main(RotatingKeys.scala:37)
at playground.Main.main(RotatingKeys.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: playground.RotatingKeys
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: playground.RotatingKeys, value: playground.RotatingKeys@e07b4db)
```

the code is as follow

```scala
import org.apache.logging.log4j.{LogManager, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

class RotatingKeys(spark: SparkSession, nRotations: Integer) {
  import spark.implicits._

  val logger: Logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass)

  logger.info("Initializing KeyRotatorJob")

  def rotateKeyUdf: UserDefinedFunction = {
    udf{ key: String => rotatekey(key, nRotations) }
  }

  def rotatekey(key: String, nRotations: Integer): String =
    key.substring(nRotations) + key.substring(0, nRotations)

  def run(): Unit =
    spark
      .sql("SELECT '0123456' as key")
      .withColumn("rotated_key", rotateKeyUdf($"key"))
      .show()
}

object Main {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Run Trials")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val rkRun = new RotatingKeys(spark,4)
    rkRun.run()
  }
}
```

It was working fine

```scala
+-------+-----------+
|    key|rotated_key|
+-------+-----------+
|0123456|    4560123|
+-------+-----------+
```

Please some help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Move your UDF from class to object main or any other object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use member of class(variables/methods) directly inside the udf closure. (If you wanted to use it directly then the class must be Serializable) send it separately as column like-

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

// SO=63064483
class RotatingKeys(spark: SparkSession, nRotations: Integer) {
  import spark.implicits._

  val logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass)

  logger.info("Initializing KeyRotatorJob")

  def rotateKeyUdf: UserDefinedFunction = {
    udf{ (key: String, nRotations: Integer) => key.substring(nRotations) + key.substring(0, nRotations) }
  }

  def run(): Unit =
    spark
      .sql("SELECT '0123456' as key")
      .withColumn("rotated_key", rotateKeyUdf($"key", lit(nRotations)))
      .show()
}

object Main {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Run Trials")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val rkRun = new RotatingKeys(spark,4)
    rkRun.run()
  }
}
```

If you wanted to use methods (`rotatekey`), make it as utility and move it to object as below-

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

// SO=63064483
class RotatingKeys(spark: SparkSession, nRotations: Integer) {
  import spark.implicits._

  val logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass)

  logger.info("Initializing KeyRotatorJob")

  def run(): Unit =
    spark
      .sql("SELECT '0123456' as key")
      .withColumn("rotated_key", Main.rotateKeyUdf($"key", lit(nRotations)))
      .show()
}

object Main {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Run Trials")
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .getOrCreate()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val rkRun = new RotatingKeys(spark,4)
    rkRun.run()
  }

  def rotateKeyUdf: UserDefinedFunction = {
    udf{ (key: String, nRotations: Integer) => rotatekey(key, nRotations) }
  }

  def rotatekey(key: String, nRotations: Integer): String =
    key.substring(nRotations) + key.substring(0, nRotations)
}
```